# Changing IP of msloop

Tags: c#, performance, ip-address

This changes the IP of msloop using `WMI(Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration)`, which takes about 1~2sec.

But, if I work on another computer, it works much much slower, for about 50~60sec.

**My Computer:**

OS: Window 7 Professional
RAM: 8GB

**Another Computer:**

OS: Window XP SP3
RAM: 2GB

```
public void setIP () {
    ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
    ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

    foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC) {
        if (!(bool) objMO["IPEnabled"]) {
            continue;
        } else if ((String) objMO["ServiceName"] != "msloop") {
            continue;
        }

        try {
            ManagementBaseObject objNewIP = objMO.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
            ManagementBaseObject objNewGate = objMO.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");

            objNewIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { "110.110.110.1" };
            objNewIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { "255.255.255.252" };

            objNewGate["GatewayCostMetric"] = new string[] { "1" };

            objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, null);
            Console.WriteLine("EnableStatic End");
            objMO.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", objNewGate, null);
            Console.WriteLine("SetGateways End");

            Console.WriteLine("Change OK");
            Console.WriteLine("==================================================================");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to Set IP : " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The result is always "Change OK". It works on XP, but very slowly.  Is the problem with the OP or the RAM?

Comment: Can you debug the code on another computer with XP? If so, what is the slowest line in the code?

Comment: Maybe Microsoft optimized the feature in windows 7.

Comment: @Dmitry > `objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", objNewIP, null);` is slowly.

Comment: Check out this app. It sets the ips of both wifi and ethernet. Also highlights current configuration with cyned coloured buttons. https://github.com/kamran7679/ConfigureIP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't help with the speed question but some generic remarks:

1. Both `ManagementClass` and `ManagementObjectCollection` are `IDisposable` and should therefore be wrapped in a `using` block to make sure any unmanaged resources are properly released.
2. Prefixing all your local variables with `obj` smells like hungarian notation and is generally discouraged. It adds not value and just clutter. Your variable names should indicate what they represent and not what type they are.
3. In C# land the common naming convention for methods is `PascalCase` and not `camelCase`. It pays to stick to general naming conventions for the ecosystem you are working in as it will make your code look more familiar to other developers.

Answer (score 2):

*This should be considered an extension to ChrisWue's answer which discusses `IDisposable` objects and appropriate method naming.*

```
objNewIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { "110.110.110.1" };
```

Has a couple of problems, there is a 'magic number' which we can live with if it must be hardcoded, although it would be better coming from a configuration file or setting.  The bigger problem is that unless you are an employee of HEXIE Information technology Co., Ltd who [own that address block](http://www.techzoom.net/Tools/IPAddressLookup?ip=110.110.110.1) then stick to assigning to number ranges reserved for 'private use' like 192.168.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/8 for example which give more than enough scope.

```
if (!(bool) objMO["IPEnabled"]) {
```

Is there a way to refactor this to make it clearer?

Looking at the performance issue you have invoking `EnableStatic` you might want to look at [StackOverflow: Problems using the WMI EnableStatic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627487/problems-using-the-wmi-enablestatic-method)